# Mostrar datos de varias listas C++

Tags: c++

Mi idea es pedirle al usuario 3 datos a traves de un menu (aun no lo hice) en donde el decidira si seguir o finalizar. Lo que necesito es que al final se muestre una lista con todos los datos ingresados pero no se me ocurre como implementarlo.

Por ejemplo: si yo pedi nombre1, estado1, empresa1 y luego el usuario quiso seguir con otro cliente y tengo nombre2,estado2,empresa2. Quiero que al final se muestren los datos de ambos.

Se me ocurre hacer un arreglo por cada persona a medida que se necesite pero no sabria como implementar eso.

Mi código hasta ahora:

```
int main (){
string nombre,estado,empresa;
nombre="Ignacio";
estado="Alta";
empresa="Arcor";

listaClientes (nombre,estado,empresa);

}



void listaClientes (string nombre, string est,string emp){

string Lista[3]={nombre,est,emp};

for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout<<Lista[i]<<endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas guardar varios valores que están relacionados entre sí, eso se traduce en una estructura

```
struct Cliente
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::string estado;
    std::string empresa;
};
```

Ahora necesitas guardar una serie de objetos de tipo "Cliente" ... necesitas una lista. La opción más simple sería utilizar un contenedor de la STL:

```
std::vector<Cliente> lista_clientes;
```

Entonces, para añadir un cliente:

```
Cliente cliente;
std::cin >> cliente.nombre >> cliente.estado >> cliente.empresa;

lista_clientes.push_back(cliente);
```

Y para imprimir los datos de la lista:

```
for (Cliente const& cliente : lista_clientes)
{
    std::cout << cliente.nombre << ' ' << cliente.estado << ' ' << cliente.empresa << '\n';
}
```